# Why doesn't worksheet.get() function from gspread work?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

The documentation for gspread says there is a function .get() to read values from a range of cells on a google sheet. When I try to use it, the python debugger spits out the error: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'get'.

```
worksheet = gc.open('Todays Route Sheet').worksheet('Roll Off')

print(worksheet.get('A1:I29'))
```

Here is a link to the documention: https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.get

Answer (score 3):

When I saw [the official document of `get(range_name=None, **kwargs)`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.get), I could confirm "New in version 3.3.".

So please use the latest version of gspread and test it again.

When I tested your script at the latest version (in the current stage, it's v3.6.0), I could confirm that your script worked.

#### Reference:

- [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)